# Postgres function returning a string from a select statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to get this function to return a string that comes from the SELECT statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.fnRepID (pram_ID BIGINT)
RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE 
    pram varchar := '';
BEGIN
    SELECT pram =  pram || (Case COALESCE(a.Name, '') WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END )
        || (Case COALESCE(b.Name, '' ) WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END )
        || f.NAME || ';'
    FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ClassRelationship b ON a.ParentClassID = b.ClassID and b.Type = 2 and a.Type = 1;
 
    RETURN pram;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dbo.fnRepID (BIGINT) TO "postgres";
```

And this function creation seem to go through just fine, now I want to call this function with 0 as pram_ID but it's saying this basically no matter what I do.

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dbo.fnrepid(bigint) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT dbo.fnRepID(0)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at PERFORM
SQL state: 42601
```

I have tried a DO PERFORM block as I have seen similar examples
`DO $$ BEGIN PERFORM dbo.fnRepID(0); END $$;`but I basically want to get the return value from this function somehow. If there's anything wrong with my procedures please let me know, as I am new to postgres. Thank you.

Edit: Would the following work if I want to append each row of the results into the same var? (can I use select into with the variable on both sides to append to itself?)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.fnRepID (pram_ID BIGINT)
RETURNS varchar AS $$
DECLARE 
    pram varchar := '';
BEGIN
    SELECT pram || (Case COALESCE(a.Name, '') WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END )
        || (Case COALESCE(b.Name, '' ) WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END )
        || f.NAME || ';' INTO pram
    FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ClassRelationship b ON a.ParentClassID = b.ClassID and b.Type = 2 and a.Type = 1;
 
    RETURN pram;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION dbo.fnRepID (BIGINT) TO "postgres";
```

Comment: What is the intention behind `pram = ''....`? That expression will create a boolean value that indicates if the variable `pram` is equal to the string.

Comment: Why a function? A view could do the same and is much simpler

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to have pram take on the value on the right side and have everything appended to pram, now I see how the equal sign would just produce a boolean but not sure how I can make it do what I want.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm looking to return basically a continuous string to pass to somewhere else and I can't easily change something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing

```
SELECT pram = (…) FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a …;
```

where `(…)` is an expression that is evaluated and then **compared** to the current value of `pram` (which was initialised to an empty string). The query does nothing else, there is no destination for this boolean value (comparison result) it computes, you're getting an error.

You most likely meant to either perform an [assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)

```
pram = SELECT (…) FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a …;
```

or use an [`INTO` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

```
SELECT (…) INTO pram FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a …;
```

---

Notice that you don't even need pl/pgsql to do this. A plain sql function would do as well:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.fnRepID(pram_ID BIGINT) RETURNS varchar
LANGUAGE sql
STABLE
RETURN (
  SELECT
    '' ||
    (CASE COALESCE(a.Name, '') WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END) ||
    (CASE COALESCE(b.Name, '' ) WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE b.Name || ' - ' END) ||
    f.NAME ||
    ';'
  FROM dbo.ClassRelationship a
  LEFT JOIN dbo.ClassRelationship b ON a.ParentClassID = b.ClassID AND b.Type = 2 AND a.Type = 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I previously thought the equal sign here can be just a value assignment (I think sql server can be written like this). This is still somewhat problematic for me, since the string I want to output is supposed to be a concatenation of all potential returned rows, but this simple assignment might not be what I expect when the SELECT statement returns a multi row table. How would that behave here?

Comment: Asking specifically about the plain sql function, wouldn't that select statement want to return a multiline table in this case? Or can you simply cast it to a varchar when returning, would that still give an appended long string in one line?

Comment: To concatenate the values from all the rows into a single string, use [`string_agg(…)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html). Otherwise it'll be an error to select multiple rows (with any syntax). I had assumed the query in the question was a bit incomplete and you might also have some `WHERE` clause in it, since you're not using the `pram_ID` parameter anywhere.